# Display an image in a fixed position when hovering over a row of a table generated with php from a database query

Tags: javascript

I want to show an image when hovering over a table row. I want to know how to pass an argument to the `showCard` function for building the link dynamically with `link = "http..." + name`. And why does the function get a `this` argument when there's nothing in the function declaration?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #cardImage {
          position: fixed;
          float: right;
          top: 5%;
          right: 3%;
          width: 223px;
          height: 310px;
      }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- This would be a table ganerated in another file -->
  <!-- Each row of the table would show a different image when hovering over it -->
  <?php
    echo "<center><h2>Cardlist</h2></center>";
    echo "<div><img id='cardImage' src='http://jpdefault.comuv.com/heirloom/gfx/card_back.jpg'</div>";
    echo "<center><table><thead><tr><th>NAME</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    $name = "Llanowar Elves";
    // I want to pass the variable which would be taken from a database $row['name'] to the javascript function
    echo "<tr><td><center><span onmouseover='showCard(this)'>Load image</span></center></td></tr>";
    echo "</tbody></table></center>"
  ?>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showCard() {
  var image = document.getElementById('cardImage');
  image.setAttribute('src', 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?&type=card&name=Llanowar Elves');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<span onmouseover="showCard(this)">Load image</span></center>
```

in here when you pass the argument "this" in the onclick of the span element, it passes the html dom element to the js function. you can reference it as such:

```
function showCard(el) {
  //el being the html dom element.
  var image = document.getElementById('cardImage');
  image.setAttribute('src', 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?&type=card&name=Llanowar Elves');
  }
```

if you are trying to pass variables to your function, i suggest attaching it as "data" variables and adding the onclick function from the code. For example:

```
<span id="span1" data-val="somestuff" data-anotherval="someotherstuff">Load image</span>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("span1");
    var somestuff = el.dataset.somestuff;
    var someotherstuff = el.dataset.someotherstuff;
    var html = "http://" + somestuff + "/" + someotherstuff;
    el.onmouseover= function() {
    //do stuff 
    }
...
</script>
```

Or you can directly access them from the function... such as:

```
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("span1");

    el.onmouseover= function() {        
    var somestuff = el.dataset.somestuff;
    var someotherstuff = el.dataset.someotherstuff;
    var html = "http://" + somestuff + "/" + someotherstuff;
    //do stuff 
    }
...
</script>
```

if you generate spans too, then you can attach a specific class to everyone of them and select class and attach function to them. for example:

```
<span class="someuniqueclassname" data-val="somestuff" data-anotherval="someotherstuff">Load image</span>
<span class="someuniqueclassname" data-val="somestuff2" data-anotherval="someotherstuff2">Load image</span>
<script>
    var mouseoverfunction = function() {        
        var somestuff = this.dataset.somestuff;
        var someotherstuff =this.dataset.someotherstuff;
        var html = "http://" + somestuff + "/" + someotherstuff;
        //do stuff 
        ...
    }

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("span1");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var el = elements[i];
        el.onmouseover = mouseoverfunction;
    } 
</script>
```

i forgot earlier "this" refers to wherever the function called from, aka "owner" of the function. in "mouseoverfunction" it refers to the element...

Comment: But how do I know what is `"span1"` because it has to be different for each item as the list is generated by a database search so it would have to be equal to the name. How do I pass the name to the script?